# Nested accordions with expressions as labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have one main accordion which consists of nested accordions. And the label of the accordions is associated with expressions like `{{week.weekStartDate}}` But when I click on the main accordion all the nested accordions are opening up and If I close any one nested accordion, the all the nested accordions are closing and only one main accordion is remaining. I don't want this to happen. I want all the nested accordions to open separately. How am I supposed to do that?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="panel">
 <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 35px;">
    <h4 class="panel-title" style="line-height: 10px;">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" translate>     <label>LOGIN_PERSON_OWN_EVENTS</label></a> 
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
    </h4>
    </div>


<tbody data-ng-repeat="week in weekInfo">
  <tr style="height: 35px">
    <th colspan="10" style="padding: 0px; height: 35px; width: 100%;">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-align">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="line-height: 10px;">
         <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
         data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-1">{{week.weekNo}} </label> 
<label class="control-label col-sm-6">{{week.weekStartDate}}
    {{week.weekEndDate}}</label> 
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"style="margin-right: 15px"></i>
    </div>
    </a>
</h4>
</div>
</th>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please create fiddle if possible

Comment: It looks like all the accordions have the same target href.  Not sure where this ID is set, but that's probably why this is happening.  Different accordions should have different ideas.

Comment: where am I supposed to create different id's? In the nested accordion?

Comment: @raduation Can you please tell me which id are you talking about?

Comment: #collapseOne ... this is presumably the accordion getting collapsed when you click on the link.  Well, if all of them have this ID, all of them will get collapsed / uncollapsed.  I don't see where the ID gets set though.

Comment: Okay. I will try., Thank you